# Web Scraping: Como alterar o valor de um botão drop down de um site usando R?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

Desejo criar um script em R para ler uma tabela HTML. Fazer isso de uma página estática com o pacote `rvest` é fácil, o problema é que eu tenho que alterar o valor de dois botões da página.

O site é este [aqui](http://www.agrolink.com.br/cotacoes/historico/ba/algodao-em-pluma-15kg). Note que acima do gráfico, ele tem dois botões: um relacionado ao estado (`ctl00$cphConteudo$CpDDLEstado`) e outro relacionado a um produto agrícola (`ctl00$cphConteudo$CpDDLProduto`).

Tentei o seguinte código sem sucesso:

```
library(rvest)
url <- "http://www.agrolink.com.br/cotacoes/historico/rs/leite-1l"
pgsession <- html_session(url)               ## create session
pgform    <- html_form(pgsession)[[1]]       ## pull form from session
filled_form <- set_values(pgform,
                          `ctl00$cphConteudo$CpDDLEstado` = "9826", #bahia
                          `ctl00$cphConteudo$CpDDLProduto` = "17") # algodão

submit_form(pgsession,filled_form)
```

O código retorna um link de uma página em branco.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esse site tem uma forma muito chata de fazer requisição `POST`, mas ele tem a vantagem de aceitar requisições `GET` também. Para o `GET`, ele usa um formato

```
http://www.agrolink.com.br/cotacoes/historico/#ESTADO/#NOME_PRODUTO
```

Testando alguns vi que ele sempre usa em `#ESTADO`, a sigla do estado em letra minúscula. Para o nome do produto, vi que ele trocou tudo que não era alfa-numérico por `-`.

Então, você poderia converter o nome dos produtos com uma função do tipo:

```
library(stringr)
produtos <- c("Banana Prata Anã Primeira Atacado Cx 20Kg",
              "Cebola Amarela (Ipa) Produtor 1Kg",
              "Açúcar VHP Sc 50Kg"
              )

produtos <- produtos %>% str_replace_all("[:punct:]", "-") %>%
  str_replace_all("[:space:]", "-") %>%
  tolower() %>%
  iconv(to = "ASCII//TRANSLIT")
produtos
[1] "banana-prata-ana-primeira-atacado-cx-20kg" "cebola-amarela--ipa--produtor-1kg"        
[3] "acucar-vhp-sc-50kg"
```

Depois você pode fazer a requisição desta forma, acessando cada uma das páginas com um laço que percorra o vetor de estados e de produtos:

```
estados <- c("sp", "mg")
for(estado in estados){
  for(produto in produtos){
    url <- sprintf("http://www.agrolink.com.br/cotacoes/historico/%s/%s", estado, produto)
    tabela <- read_html(url) %>%
      html_nodes("#ctl00_cphConteudo_gvHistorico") %>%
      html_table()
    tabela <- tabela[[1]]
  }
}
```

Claro que deste jeito, você ainda vai precisar criar na mão uma lista com o nome dos produtos e uma lista com a sigla dos estados, mas acredito que seja a forma mais fácil.

Comment: Muito bom! Me fez lembrar que preciso estudar expressões regulares.